# Existence of a 10 term sequence satisfying a condition

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist a sequence of 10 positive integers $x_1,x_2,\cdots{},x_{10}$ such that $\frac{1}{x_k}=\frac{1}{x_{k-2}}-\frac{1}{x_{k-1}}$?

I managed to show a closed form for $x_j$ by induction and it turned out to be 
$$x_j=\frac{x_1x_2}{(-1)^{j+1}x_2F_{j-2}+(-1)^j x_1 F_{j-1}},$$

where $F_n$ denotes the $n$-th Fibonacci number. Hence this gave me a series of divisibility tests, and it doesn't really look promising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  It is easier to start from the back end, because then the recurrence becomes $\frac 1{x_k}+\frac 1{x_{k-1}}=\frac 1{x_{k-2}}$ and the fact that it is addition means you can never go negative.  Also $x_{k-2}$ will be rational, so you can clear fractions.  Start from $1+1=2, 1+2=3$ and continue, then divide by the product of all the numbers you use, then invert them.  We finally divide by $2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 8 \cdot 13 \cdot 21 \cdot 34 \cdot 55= 122,522,400$, so the numbers are $$x_i=\frac {122,52,400}{F_{11-i}}$$

Comment: But $\frac{1}{128}=\frac{1}{x_7}=\frac{1}{x_8}+\frac{1}{x_9}=\frac{1}{256}+\frac{1}{512}=\frac{3}{512}$ which is not true.

Comment: I was thinking that you summed all the terms remaining, which is not what you asked.    Fixing

Comment: Ah! That sounds about right.

Comment: I had the final answer upside down.  Fixed.